# Will the Azure Kinect also support the HoloLens 2 hand tracking API?

Tags: azure, hololens, azurekinect

I want to set up the new Azure Kinect service to support the HoloLens 2 hand tracking API. Is this possible? Will it be supported in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will not be supporting it at this time. You can leave a request for this in User Voice. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback